# How to recover an hacked Facebook profile

Tags: facebook, account-recovery, hacked, facebook-account

I need to recover a facebook account that has been hacked. After extensive search on the web I couldn't find a solution.

### What they did

Months ago the account was violated: email, password and the recovery phone number  have been changed. The hacker is now using the profile publishing contents.

### What I tried

- Me and several friends of the owner have reported the profile as fake, but no action has been taken by Facebook yet.

I tried, but **I can't do the password recovery** either:

- **with the email or phone**. They have been changed, and the user never received a notification when it happened (contrarily to what it should according to the facebook support center).
- **with trusted contacts**. Some tutorials around the internet still mention this solution, but apparently Facebook deactivated it.
- **using an old password**. The user doesn't remember it anymore.
- **using a device from which the user logged in recently**. I don't have one.

### Current status

- I only have the facebook username of this account (this wasn't changed by the hacker).
- The hacker kept the old profile pictures too, so it's manifest that the account is fake.
- The account has been reported to the authorities of the home country of the owner. It's not the US, so I think this will be of little help.

---

Does any of you know a solution to my problem?
It would be also great if someone knew how to speak with real person of the Facebook support center (without using a business account).